# Background-Image Icon not appearing on HTML page

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to add an Icon to a button, but for some reason it is not working. Another webpage which has similar code does work. I took the url image of that page plugged it into mine and it doesn't work.

I've used the W3C CSS validator tool and it didn't show any errors directly related to that section. I used jsfiddle to see if the problem persists using some online icon font bank and  it still didnt work.

here is the css:

```
.registration-buttons {
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    max-width:275px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    background:rgb(0,121,192);
    color: white !important;
    font: 16px/40px "Rockwell W01","Rockwell",Georgia,Courier,serif !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
    .registration-buttons:hover {
        background:rgb(0,152,242);
    }

#StartTeamBTN {
    background-image:url(../custom/SLOPES_BC/images/gui/start-team-icon.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#JoinTeamBTN {
    background-image:url(../custom/SLOPES_BC/images/gui/join-team-icon.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#RegisterIndividualBTN {
    background-image:url(../mResponsive/images/register-individual-icon.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<p><strong>Select one of the below options to Start a Team, Join a Team, or Register as an Individual. </strong></p>
<p>

<a class="registration-buttons" id="RegisterIndividualBTN" href="">Register as an Individual</a>

<a class="registration-buttons" id="StartTeamBTN" href="">
Start a Team</a>

<a class="registration-buttons" id="JoinTeamBTN" href="">Join a Team</a>

</p>
```

if it matters, the `href` is filled in, in my actual css document.

Now, I know the code works based on me being able to change the colour in ID `#RegisterIndividualBTN`, so it is calling it correctly, I just don't understand why the icon doesn't appear in the html page next to the button.

Comment: Have a look at  : https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: I didn't see any problems with your code when I dropped it into JSFiddle & updated the paths. Just make sure that you have the icons on your web server. Both relative paths & absolute paths work (but only the absolute ones work on jsfiddle with their logo). See: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/se2oesfw/

Comment: @Clomp hmm i think there's something wrong with my css as a whole. Because I tried using your icon links and Satya's and it doesn't work. This is so weird.

Comment: @Clomp ok so i fixed the issue of it not appearing at all. Seems now like it is my link itself that is broken! thanks Clomp. considering you did give me the solution before Satya, do you wanna submit your answer and I can approve it or do you not care?

Comment: @Roy that's an excellent resource! thanks man this will help loads rather than having to make my own everytime lol

Comment: @Umeed Sure. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any problems with your code when I dropped it into JSFiddle & updated the paths. Just make sure that you have the icons on your web server. Both relative paths & absolute paths work (but only the absolute ones work on jsfiddle with their logo). See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/se2oesfw).

The only thing that I've changed is these URL paths in the CSS:

```
#StartTeamBTN {
    background-image:url(https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo@2x.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#JoinTeamBTN {
    background-image:url(https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo@2x.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#RegisterIndividualBTN {
    background-image:url(https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo@2x.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

I think your background image url is incorrect.

Created a jsfiddle and it is working fine:

```
 ----      https://jsfiddle.net/Ljt1bt90/6/
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I believe the issue is with my entire CSS code, it seems something is causing a problem as I've tried both yours and Clomp's links and the icons do not load in my page.